# How to Replicate Schema changes using the SQL Replication in IBM DB2?

Tags: db2, replication, database-replication

I have configured SQL Replication between two our two IBM DB2 databases ( database A and database B). The replication is working fine and all the data changes in one database are being replicated to the other database.

The issue I am facing is that if I add a new table in database A, then I have to manually add this table in Capture Control Server and Apply Control Server.

Even If I add a new column in a table for whom SQL Replication is already configured, I have to register that column in Capture Control Server and Apply Control Server.

Is there any way of replicating the schema changes automatically from one database to the other so that we don't have to manually add the new tables and columns in Capture Control Server and Apply Control Server for SQL Replication?

Regards,

Babar Hussain

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same question and have found conflicting information in IBM's documentation...